# Routing between the instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, routing, amazon-vpc

I have two instances in the same VPC: Linux (172.31.25.177) and Windows (172.31.26.178). I opened all ports in the security group for both IP addresses and they can to connect to each other.

Windows is connected to the on-premise VPN device. 
I would like to route the packets from Linux to my site through Windows.

I had set-up RRAS on Windows and specified his internal IP as a gateway to my site network (10.98.0.0/16) in the Linux.

```
root@ip-172-31-25-177:~# ip route show
default via 172.31.16.1 dev eth0
10.98.0.0/16 via 172.31.26.178 dev eth0
```

But I see that no packets coming to the Windows from Linux (172.31.25.177) when I tried to connect to the site resources.

What I need to configure on VPC to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add routes to the main route table object for the VPC.

In the web console go to the *VPC management page* and click on **Route Tables** as seen in the menu at the left.  Select the main route table (**Yes** under **Main**).  In the lower part of the page click the **Routes** tab and you will see a routes list.  Click the blue **Edit** tab.  Click **Add another route** below the list.  Enter your CIDR subnet under **Destination**.  Enter the instance ID or Network Interface object ID of the Windows instance under **Target**.  Click **Save** when you are sure all is right.  Back in the *EC2 Instaces page* select the Windows instance.  Go to *Actions>>Networking>>Change Source/Dest. Check*.  **Disable** *Source/Dest. Check* so it allows packets to/from the Linux instance.

Comment: Also, you do not need to add static routes to any of the instances.  The VPC routing tables should be used for all routing configuration within the VPC, with instances using their default route.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify VPC routing table. You need to add static route to your site subnet and use IP of windows as gateway. Windows instance needs to set Source/dest. check to False. Your routing table will looks like this:

```
172.31.0.0/16   local                      Active  No
0.0.0.0/0       igw-xxxxxxxx               Active  No <-- this is your VPC internet gateway ID
10.98.0.0/16    eni-xxxxxxxx / i-xxxxxxxx  Active  No <-- this is windows instance
```

Everything else will manage AWS.